# How to convert JSON to Array in JQuery (from the output)?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am struggling with converting JSON result to JQuery Array. Please share your ideas how to achieve this.

My JSON Result is as below:

```
0:{Business: "DS", DocCount: 18, NextReviewCount: 14, UptoDateCount: 1, OverDueCount: 3,url:"link1.html"}
1:{Business: "MRCSB", DocCount: 15, NextReviewCount: 14, UptoDateCount: 1, OverDueCount: 0,url:"link1.html"}
2:{Business: "PCGB", DocCount: 18, NextReviewCount: 12, UptoDateCount: 2, OverDueCount: 4,url:"link1.html"}
3:{Business: "PGB", DocCount: 10, NextReviewCount: 8, UptoDateCount: 1, OverDueCount: 1,url:"link1.html"}
```

I need to build an array like below:

```
var cXample=[
[[10,'PGB','link1.html'], [18,'DS','link1.html'], [15,'MRCSB','link1.html'], [18,'PCGB','link1.html']],
 [[8,'PGB','link1.html'], [14,'DS','link1.html'], [14,'MRCSB','link1.html'], [12,'PCGB','link1.html']], 
[[1,'PGB','link1.html'], [1,'DS','link1.html'], [1,'MRCSB','link1.html'], [2,'PCGB','link1.html']],
[[1,'PGB','link1.html'], [3,'DS','link1.html'], [0,'MRCSB','link1.html'], [4,'PCGB','link1.html']]
];
```

I needs to show this result as a bar chart .

Comment: Where are the "link1.html" coming from? and the "MRCSB" strings?

Comment: Why you want to convert into in array? Can you explain what you want to achieve after converting into array?

Comment: I needs to show this result as a bar chart .

Comment: @Adam yes, MRCSB is a string and I missed the url in the jquery result. Just now I updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

var array = $.map(parseResult , function (item, index) {

```
                        return [[item.DocCount,item.Business, item.url,0],[ item.NextReviewCount,item.Business,  item.url,1],[ item.OverDueCount, item.Business, item.url,2],[item.UptoDateCount, item.Business,  item.url,3]];


                    }); 

                    var arrayShortBySerl=array.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
// Ascending: first age less than the previous
return obj1[3]- obj2[3];
```

});

for(var i=0;i<((arrayShortBySerl.length)/4);i++)
 {
  arryChart.push([arrayShortBySerl[i*4], arrayShortBySerl[(i*4)+1], arrayShortBySerl[(i*4)+2], arrayShortBySerl[(i*4)+3]]);
  }